# Function declaration in static library in C

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, compiler-warnings, unix-ar

I've a problem when I try to compile my program with my static library.
I create the object file of my .c files whith `gcc -c ft_putstr.c`. Then I execute `ar -rcs libft.a ft_putstr.o` and then I make `gcc main.c -L. -lft` and I've

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'ft_putstr' is invalid in
>   C99.

The binary is created but I don't want this warning even if it's work like that.
It works if I had the flag `-std="c89"` on GCC but I have tu use C99.

This is my main :

```
int main(void)
{
     ft_putstr("Bonjour");
     return (0);
}
```

This my ft_putstr.c :

```
#include <unistd.h>

    void    ft_putstr(char *str) 
    {
         (*str) ? write(1, str, 1), ft_putstr(str + 1) : 0; 
    }
```

Comment: Do you import `ft_putstr.h` from `main.c`?  Does that header define the function?

Comment: No, I don't import it because I've seen a video (given by my school) which make work the program without any .h. I've already tried with a .h and yes it works.

Comment: The problem is that `main()` cannot see it. Put it in a header and include it in the file with `main()` If you can't import a header, then just declare it static extern in one file and include the prototype in the file with `main`

Comment: Without declaring `ft_putstr`, you're always going to get an implicit declaration warning.  Hell, you could declare it in main.c if you want (please don't though; that'd be stupid).

Comment: I think than you have a very higher level than the mine so I will add a header file, this is the better option I think now. Many thanks for your help and sorry if I was unpleasant. It does more than 2 hours than I'm on it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what is "static extern"?

Comment: You will need to declare the function in one file completely. In your case it is not declared in the file with main. Then in the file with main add a `extern` declaration. (i.e. `extern void ft_putstr(char *str);`

Comment: @sapi declaring it in main.c is slightly better than not declaring it at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include a header file which has a declaration like

```
void    ft_putstr(char *str);
```

or you can insert this line in your `main.c`

```
extern void    ft_putstr(char *str);
```

Comment: `extern` is superfluous here, all function declarations are extern unless you specifically indicate `static`.